# Adding JSON layers to a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am trying to get familiar with leaflet maps, however I am not finding their tutorials very intuitive. I have been using their geojson tutorial and looking through the source code of their examples to try and add my own data to a map I am creating, however I have not been successful in having the polygon display.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html>
<head>

<title>Leaflet Ex</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="creek.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="mapid" style="width: 1000px; height: 700px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var map = L.map('mapid').setView([49.2485, -122.9995], 15);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/***/civ43lux700032iqp0990mgfn/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGd3YWx0b24iLCJhIjoiSUZURmlaUSJ9.FLL81KvyJ3kCFiUbUgCAWg', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);

        L.geoJson(creek, {
            style: function (feature) {
                return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
            }
        }).addTo(map);

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

json:

```
var creek = {

"type": = "Feature",
"properties": {
    "AREA":4575.273,
    "PERIMETER":1396.149,
    "CREEK_":2,
    "CREEK_ID":5,
    "TYPE":"water",
    "CODE":"Guichion Creek"
    "style": {
        weight: 1,
        color: "#000",
        opacity: 1,
        fillColor: "#0D00F2",
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    }   
}
"geometry": { 
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [500001.59375,5455104],[500001.84375,5455110],[500010.09375,5455109.5],[500012.5,5455105.5],[500013.15625,5455100.5],[500013.78125,5455094],[500014.4375,5455085.5],[500014.4375,5455080],[500014.4375,5455076],[500013.5625,5455073.5],[500012.28125,5455068.5],[500010.75,5455065.5],[500008.59375,5455062.5],[500006.4375,5455059],[500004.90625,5455057],[500004.90625,5455049],[500004.90625,5455042.5],[500005.34375,5455038],[500006,5455031.5],[500006,5455028.5],[500006.4375,5455024.5],[500007.5,5455021],[500009.25,5455016.5],[500010.53125,5455014],[500010.96875,5455010],[500011.1875,5455005],[500011.84375,5454999.5],[500012.28125,5454991.5],[500013.78125,5454982.5],[500015.53125,5454975.5],[500016.84375,5454969],[500018.78125,5454964.5],[500019.875,5454959.5],[500022.25,5454947.5],[500023.96875,5454941.5],[500025.71875,5454936.5],[500026.375,5454928],[500027.25,5454921.5],[500026.59375,5454910.5],[500026.15625,5454906],[500026.375,5454893.5],[500027.03125,5454887],[500027.03125,5454881],[500027.25,5454876],[500027.875,5454871],[500028.96875,5454868.5],[500032.4375,5454864],[500033.96875,5454861],[500034.59375,5454856.5],[500033.75,5454851.5],[500031.125,5454847],[500028.75,5454842],[500026.59375,5454840.5],[500023.34375,5454838],[500020.5,5454836],[500019.65625,5454831.5],[500019.21875,5454826],[500017.46875,5454820.5],[500017.46875,5454814],[500016.40625,5454807],[500015.3125,5454801],[500014.21875,5454796],[500014,5454790.5],[500013.15625,5454786],[500013.5625,5454779],[500012.71875,5454775],[500011.40625,5454770.5],[500010.96875,5454760],[500011.1875,5454744],[500011.40625,5454734],[500010.53125,5454727.5],[500009.03125,5454721],[500008.375,5454712.5],[500006.4375,5454702],[500005.34375,5454694],[500004.46875,5454687],[500003.59375,5454683],[500003.375,5454673],[500003.15625,5454667],[500001.65625,5454659],[500000.78125,5454650.5],[500000.125,5454643],[499999.28125,5454639],[499998.40625,5454634.5],[499997.75,5454629.5],[499997.09375,5454624.5],[499996.21875,5454621.5],[499995.375,5454617.5],[499993.1875,5454613],[499991.25,5454609],[499991.03125,5454602.5],[499990.375,5454597.5],[499988,5454592],[499986.6875,5454588.5],[499986.03125,5454583.5],[499985.8125,5454578],[499984.53125,5454572],[499983.4375,5454561.5],[499981.9375,5454555],[499980.40625,5454550],[499980.40625,5454542],[499980.84375,5454532.5],[499978.6875,5454522.5],[499978.46875,5454517],[499977.375,5454514],[499971.9375,5454506],[499965.65625,5454499],[499958.28125,5454491],[499953.09375,5454486.5],[499947.03125,5454483],[499938.125,5454478],[499930.53125,5454474.5],[499922.53125,5454469.5],[499916.65625,5454464],[499914.0625,5454467],[499918.40625,5454470],[499922.75,5454474],[499929.03125,5454478.5],[499931.1875,5454479.5],[499935.09375,5454480],[499941.59375,5454484.5],[499952.65625,5454491.5],[499958.5,5454498.5],[499964.15625,5454504],[499968.46875,5454508],[499973.46875,5454523.5],[499975.40625,5454531.5],[499976.28125,5454546.5],[499978.46875,5454556],[499979.53125,5454566],[499981.9375,5454585],[499985.625,5454599.5],[499988.21875,5454615],[499992.125,5454629],[499994.9375,5454642],[499998.625,5454653],[499998.40625,5454660],[500000.78125,5454674.5],[500001,5454688.5],[500001.65625,5454700.5],[500003.59375,5454709],[500005.5625,5454724],[500005.125,5454736.5],[500005.125,5454756],[500007.28125,5454782],[500008.375,5454798.5],[500010.09375,5454809.5],[500014.21875,5454830.5],[500018.125,5454848],[500019.875,5454859.5],[500022.03125,5454864],[500022.46875,5454886.5],[500022.6875,5454903.5],[500022.03125,5454928],[500020.71875,5454935.5],[500017.46875,5454940.5],[500015.3125,5454962.5],[500011.1875,5454977],[500005.78125,5454990.5],[500005.78125,5454995],[500005.5625,5455005.5],[500003.8125,5455011.5],[500001,5455019.5],[499995.59375,5455034],[499990.8125,5455050.5],[499985.8125,5455062],[499983.65625,5455065.5],[499984.09375,5455078],[499986.25,5455080.5],[499990.15625,5455083.5],[499995.15625,5455090.5],[499999.90625,5455098],[500001.59375,5455104]
                        ]
                    ]
}
};
```

any help figuring out where my problem is would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not valid JSON. This should be a red flag perhaps: `"type": = "Feature",`

Comment: Also, style property names ("weight", "color"...) should be in quotes

Answer (score 1):

Typo, right here:

```
"type": = "Feature",
```

Check the [object initializer syntax in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), notice there is no usage of the `=` operator in there.

In the future, use tools like [JSONlint](https://jsonlint.com/) and [GeoJSONLint](https://geojsonlint.com/) to check the validity of your JSON/GeoJSON. Avoid writing JSON/GeoJSON manually if possible. Use your browser's debugging capabilities to catch errors like that one.

---

Besides that, notice the coordinate system for this `L.LatLng`:

```
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([49.2485, -122.9995], 15);
```

And the coordinates in your GeoJSON:

```
[500001.59375,5455104], ...
```

Those are definitely not latitude-longitude coordinates. From the looks of it, they should be some kind of UTM coordinates (false easting and northing of 500000 and 5000000).

According to the [GeoJSON specs](https://geojson.org/), in particular [section 4 of RFC 7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-4):

> The coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates is a
> geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic
> System 1984 (WGS 84) [WGS84] datum, with longitude and latitude units
> of decimal degrees.

In other words, convert your coordinates to lat-long in WGS84 (AKA EPSG:4326) if you want to conform to the GeoJSON standard. As it is now, Leaflet will try to have a point at 500000 degrees west, 5450000 degrees north, which makes absolutely no sense.

Convert your coordinates. If you don't have any clue on how to do that, start by researching into [proj4](https://proj4.org/), related utilities like [cs2cs](https://web.archive.org/web/20161019041820/http://trac.osgeo.org:80/proj/wiki/man_cs2cs) or [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), cousin projects like [proj4js](http://proj4js.org/), or graphical GIS software like gvSIG and QGIS.

Comment: Thank you! Totally forgot about the coordinate system mismatch, so I just reprojected using FME since that's how I moved my data into json in the first place.

Comment: If you're a FME user, you should be able to reproject it to EPSG:4326 and generate GeoJSON from there, I assume?